# Save environmental variables in vagrant

Tags: vagrant, environment-variables, vagrantfile

I have CentOS7 set up via vagrant and when I `export $MYVAR=test` I can successfully `echo $MYVAR`. The problem arises when I close the vagrant session and have to ssh back in, this variable gets wiped and I have to reset it every time.

Is there a workaround for this? Possibly in the `.vagrantfile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to add your export line in your `~/.profile` file so it will always be available when you start a new session

Comment: I've tried this before, for aliases as well. Both in `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile`, I have to manually `source ~/.profile` on each session, which is annoying.

Comment: Are you sure you had this in the vagrant user home folder ?

Comment: Yes, in `~` which gives `/home/vagrant` when I `pwd`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding following to your provisioning script.

`echo "export MYVAR=test" >> ~/.profile`

On Vagrantfile, It will look like:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
echo "export MYVAR=test" >> ~/.profile
SHELL
```